# How to achieve uneven spacing between the items in tab bar?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

In my application I want to set the tab bar items at uneven positions inside the UITabbar (meaning the space between 1st and 2nd is not equal to the 2nd and 3rd and so on)
I know there is no such options as the item don't have a frame property. so is that possible to achieve this by some other ways like

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:buttonItem
```

Or is it Possible to reposition the items in the desired location inside tab bar?

Comment: Are you using images for the tabs?? If so check their sizes whether all are equal.

Comment: You can use **image insets** to shift your tabbar button image left or right and **pad** the title with white spaces, that way you can shift the whole button content to one side as if there was a space beside it..silly but can give the desired look.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, you can drag and drop a "Fixed/Flexible space bar button item" into your toolbar. This will serve as a separator between buttons. Also, Drag and drop an outlet connection to the controller if you want to control its width programmatically. You can also adjust the spacing through the inspector (look for the width property). For example if your Fixed space bar button item's outlet name is spacer, you can set the width of the spacer as follows:

self.spacer.width = 50; (or whatever value)

Hope this helps.